# How do you count how many maximum values there are in a list?

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing, max

Lets say I have the list below:

```
list1=[1,2,4,6,8,3,2,5,8,4,2]
```

I want to return the integer, 2, because 8 is the maximum value and there are two 8s in the list. How can I do this? Edit: I also want to assume that the maximum number in the list can be any negative or non-negative number including zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use something like this:

```
list1=[1,2,4,6,8,3,2,5,8,4,2]
print list1.count(max(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ans = 0
mx = 0
for x in list1:
    if x > mx:
        mx = x
        ans = 1
    elif x == mx :
        ans += 1

print ans
```

assume max number is bigger than 0, otherwise you should initial `mx` with the negative infinity

Comment: you can initial `mx = list1[0]` if the list1 is not empty

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1=[1,2,4,6,8,3,2,5,8,4,2]
>>> x = max(list1)
>>> l = []
>>> for i in list1:
    if i == x:
        l.append(i)


>>> l
[8, 8]
>>> len(l)
2
```

**OR**

```
>>> list1=[1,2,4,6,8,3,2,5,8,4,2]
>>> x = max(list1)
>>> result = len(filter(lambda i: i == x, list1))
>>> result
2
```